# PHP 7.x SQLITE3 PDO - is the execute() closing the PDO connection?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have this code that works weird with SQLITE3 , since the same code with MYSQL works fine

The issue is the line commented with "ISSUE" at line #31, because with MYSQL/MariaDB that "re connection" is NOT needed

Now I better explain

If the IF routine is not entered, I have NO error

If the IF routine is processed, line #34 throws

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare()
```

like if the *$PDO-execute();* inside the IF is destroying the PDO istance

You may say, well, no problem, now you have fixed it ... yes, but I'd like to understand why this happen.

Also portability is a point. If this is PDO ... except for the connection, the rest of the script should work and moved among various supported PDO DBs

Thank you if you kindly hint what is the reason and what is it

```
<?php

// Create or open a database file
$PDO = new PDO('sqlite:myDatabase.sqlite3');


if( isset($_POST['NoteUpdateText'])  && !empty(trim($_POST['NoteUpdateText'])) ){

    //$testo = $_POST['NoteUpdateText'];

    try {

            $PDO = $PDO->prepare('UPDATE ajax SET testo = :testo WHERE id = :id');
            $PDO->bindValue(':testo', $_POST['NoteUpdateText']);
            $PDO->bindValue(':id', 1);
            $PDO->execute();

        // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
        //echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
}

// In EVERY case, load the actual DB record and return it to javascript

$PDO = new PDO('sqlite:myDatabase.sqlite3');  // --- ISSUE, theoretically this is already opened at line #3 ---

    try {
            $PDO = $PDO->prepare('SELECT testo FROM ajax WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1'); 
            $PDO->execute(); 
            $row = $PDO->fetch();
            //var_dump($row);
            echo $row["testo"];
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }       

?>
```

FIXED CODE

```
<?php

//include 'db-con2.php';
// table: ajax  
// col: testo

// Create or open a database file
$PDO = new PDO('sqlite:myDatabase.sqlite3');

if( isset($_POST['NoteUpdateText'])  && !empty(trim($_POST['NoteUpdateText'])) ){

    //$testo = $_POST['NoteUpdateText'];

    try {

            $statement = $PDO->prepare('UPDATE ajax SET testo = :testo WHERE id = :id');
            $statement->bindValue(':testo', $_POST['NoteUpdateText']);
            $statement->bindValue(':id', 1);
            $statement->execute();

        // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
        //echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br> - IF -" . $e->getMessage();
        }
}

// carica da DB in ogni caso per caricare il P col testo realmente in DB
//$PDO = new PDO('sqlite:myDatabase.sqlite3');

    try {
            $statement = $PDO->prepare('SELECT testo FROM ajax WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1'); 
            $statement->execute(); 

            $row = $statement->fetch();
            //var_dump($row);
            echo $row["testo"];
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br> - NORMALE - " . $e->getMessage();
        }       

?>
```

Comment: `$PDO = $PDO->` don't you think it's not __ok__?

Comment: @u_mulder hi what you kindly mean? :-) . My premise is that this code with MYSQL works

Comment: I mean that `$PDO` holds __connection__ and you __overwrite it__ with PDOstatement object. And __error__ tells you about that.

Comment: OUCH! You are right!! Let me fix it

Comment: @u_mulder I have changed lines #34,35 from $PDO to $statement but now it throws Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() at line #36

Comment: I don't know what you have changed but please - check again.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you the main issue was the use of the $PDO variable for the statement if you write it in the replies I mark it as right solution

Comment: There's already exact answer.

Comment: @u_mulder I have fixed the script with your hint. Now I have added the fixed code at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you override `$PDO` variable ?

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:myDatabase.sqlite3');



if( isset($_POST['NoteUpdateText'])  && !empty(trim($_POST['NoteUpdateText'])) ){

  //$testo = $_POST['NoteUpdateText'];

 try {

   $stmt = $PDO->prepare('UPDATE ajax SET testo = :testo WHERE id = :id');
   if ($stmt->execute(array(':testo'=>$_POST['NoteUpdateText'], ':id' => 1)))
   {

     // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
     //echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
   } else {
     // There's error processing updates
     // debug
     print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
   }
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

// In EVERY case, load the actual DB record and return it to javascript

// There's no need to redeclare $PDO 
// $PDO = new PDO('sqlite:myDatabase.sqlite3');  // --- ISSUE, theoretically this is already opened at line #3 ---

  try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT testo FROM ajax WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1"); // line #34
   $stmt->execute(); 
   $row = $stmt->fetch();
   //var_dump($row);
   echo $row["testo"];
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: hi thank you this is more technical, but since I'm learning, this is a next step, can you kindly help with the original code?